# How can I create a Mongo index definition from an existing one using the C# driver?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to recreate indexes from one collection for another.

I can get the existing index from the source collection by:

```
var sourceCollectionName = "source";
var targetCollectionName = "target";

var sourceCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(sourceCollectionName);
var targetCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(targetCollectionName);

List<BsonDocument> sourceCollectionIndexes = await(await sourceCollection.Indexes.ListAsync()).ToListAsync();
```

But I cannot figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes a bit cumbersome if you want to run strongly typed .NET driver API like `targetCollection.Indexes.CreateOne()` since it requires options to be specified as `CreateIndexOptions` type which expectes all the options like `Sparse` or `Unique` to be specified in a strongly typed way.

Alternatively you can create multiple indexes using [createIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#dbcmd.createIndexes) database command. To run it from C# you can remove `ns` from obtained `BsonDocuments` since the namespace will be different and then pass all your definitions to that command. Try:

```
var sourceCollectionName = "source";
var targetCollectionName = "target";

var sourceCollection = Db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(sourceCollectionName);

List<BsonDocument> sourceCollectionIndexes = await (await sourceCollection.Indexes.ListAsync()).ToListAsync();

foreach(var indexDef in sourceCollectionIndexes)
{
    indexDef.Remove("ns");
}

await Db.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument()
{
    { "createIndexes", targetCollectionName },
    {
        "indexes", new BsonArray(sourceCollectionIndexes)
    }
});
```

Comment: Beat me by minutes. Excellent answer, I came to the same conclusion.
You can do it partially strong typed using the legacy driver however that won't support any options.